# Cant connect to local MVC 4 api server with WP8 emulator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, restsharp, windows-phone-8

I have a little game project that uses a MVC 4 api server, however since I installed windows 8 / VS12 / WP8 SDK I havent been able to access the server from my app in the emulator, I can however access the deployed webserver.

Is there some sort of default firewall that would prevent me from contacting a localhost server? I just get a NotFound exception when I try, the localhost server works fine in my browser to retrieve some xml object

I have the same code working in windows 7 with vs2010 and wp7 sdk.

To connect to the server I use http://restsharp.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emulator is running in Hyper-V, which is a **virtual machine**. It runs it's own network, and thus your PCs *"localhost"* isn't available from inside the virtual machine.

Comment: Right that makes sense, have to configure a IIS then as I wouldnt think the development server will allow outside connections, just troublesome to debug on a "real" iis server compared to the inbuild debugging

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to set up a full IIS... you can go about with IIS express ( the visual studio way when you run the Web api solution ).

You need to do 2 things, first one check

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj684580(v=vs.105).aspx - only the part called '**Quick solution with IIS Express**' ( parts 1 to 4 )

Second one, add a Microsoft Firewall rule to allow access from the VM to the IIS express.
Firewall > Advanced Settings > Rules for incoming > New port rule